# How to make custom javascript selector?

Tags: javascript, html

Example:

```
elementSelector('id')
```

I have tried many times:

```
function id(el) {
    document.getElementById(el);
}
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Try returning it. `return document.getElementById(el);` Otherwise, `undefined` is returned

Comment: He's trying to create a convenience function `id()` which will save him time every time he needs to get an element's ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your "convenience function" named `id()` to return `document.getElementById(el)`.

Here, notice the **return**:

```
function id(el){
     return document.getElementById(el);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm explaining your query with an example.

```
<button type="button" onclick="clickMe('demo')">change text in demo 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="clickMe('demo2')">change text in demo 2</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
function clickMe(id){

document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='abcdef';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In your case you need to whole object so you should return the function will be

```
function clickMe(id){

return document.getElementById(id)
    }
```

and calling it would be

```
var demo=clickMe('demo');
demo.innerHTML='demo1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is OK but you're missing the `return` keyword. If you're learning JavaScript, the new arrow function syntax can be confusing. When there's only one expression the value is returned, but when in a block (in `{}`) you need to explicitly return the value:

```
const withImplicitReturn = id => document.getElementById(id);

const withExplicitReturn = id => { return document.getElementById(id); 

const returnsUndefined = id => { document.getElementById(id); }

function alsoReturnsUndefined(id) { document.getElementById(id); }

function returnsElement(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
```

If you're ever going to use your helper function relative to another element, I'd suggest providing the parent element as an argument as well:

```
const getElementById = (parent, id) => parent ? parent.getElementById(id) : null;
// or function getElementByid(parent, id) { return parent ? parent.getElementById(id) : null; }
```